# SQL SELECT WHERE meta_keywords = '['']'

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view, empty-list

I have been having trouble query after `'['']'` in table. The data is inserted from pandas dataframe with datatype object (if it matters).

[image: A picture of a view of the table]

I want to get make a view without the empty lists. Have tried to write the empty list different ways `'['']'` , `'["''"]'` etc. but i cant get it to work.
ex `where meta_keywords <> '['']'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `meta_keywords` is a string, you would use:

```
where meta_keywords <> '['']'
```

or:

```
where meta_keywords <> '['''']'
```

Or perhaps it is hard to tell what those middle characters really are and you can use the length:

```
where length(meta_keywords) > 4
```

If it is an array (which I am guessing), then one of these might work:

```
where cardinality(meta_keywords) > 0
```

or:

```
where '' <> meta_keywords[1] and cardinality(meta_keywords) = 1
```

Comment: What does the messages mean?

Comment: me who didnt explain in detail enough but have tried ´ where meta_keywords <> '['']' ´ and it says it is not an array when i tries the other suggestion

Comment: When i copy from the table i get [''] so i really dont understand why i cant.

Comment: hell yes- where meta_keywords <> '['''']' works thank u

Comment: @Younglolk. . . Because single quotes delimit strings.  To put a single quote in a string, you need to double it up.  Hence, `'['']` is interpreted as `[']`.